# Customizing form in ASP net CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, forms

I have a form set up with validation and all. However I would like to customize it and make it look visually more appealing.

This is my form code.

```
<form action="" id="regForm">
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" DisplayMode="SingleParagraph"
        HeaderText="You must enter value in the following fields:" ShowMessageBox="True" />
    <b>Sign up information</b><br />
    <asp:Label ID="email" runat="server" Text="Email Address"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="emailbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Not a valid e-mail address. Must follow email@host.domain"
        ControlToValidate="emailbox" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="emailbox"
        Display="None" ErrorMessage="Email"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="pass1" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="pass1box"
        runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password must include one of these (!@#$%^&*+;:)"
        ControlToValidate="pass1box" ValidationExpression="(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,14})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="pass1box"
        Display="None" ErrorMessage="Password" ViewStateMode="Enabled"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="pass2" runat="server" Text="Re-enter Password"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox
        ID="pass2box" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password fields don't match"
        ControlToCompare="pass1box" ControlToValidate="pass2box"></asp:CompareValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="pass2box"
        Display="None" ErrorMessage="Re-enter Password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
    <b class="customform">Personal Information </b>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox
        ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        Display="None" ErrorMessage="First Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"
        Display="None" ErrorMessage="Last Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="State"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="38px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Zip Code"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Width="55px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Number"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" TextMode="Phone"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox6"
        ErrorMessage="Invalid Number. Must be in Format (XXX) XXX-XXXX" ValidationExpression="^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox6"
        Display="None" ErrorMessage="Phone Number"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Credit Card Information</strong><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Card Type"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="MasterCard" />
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Visa" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Card Number"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox7"
        ErrorMessage="Not a valid credit card number. Must contain 16 digits." ValidationExpression="^((4\d{3})|(5[1-5]\d{2})|(6011))-?\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}|3[4,7][\d\s-]{13}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox7"
        Display="None" ErrorMessage="Card Number"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Expiration Date"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Style="height: 22px">
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Nov 13</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Dec 13</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Jan 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Feb 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Mar 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Apr 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>May 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Jun 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>July 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Aug 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Sep 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Oct 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Nov 14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Dec 14</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"
        ErrorMessage="Expiration Date">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    </form>
```

This is my css.

```
#regForm
{
 border:1px solid black;
 background-color:#ccc;
 height:500px;
 width:750px;   
}
```

but for some reason this does not get applied. Am I doing something wrong? Is the process of styling ASP elements different to that of regular HTML elements?

I've assigned my form and id and referenced it in my css but no result...

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try applying the #regForm rule to a fieldset instead.

Comment: Styles never get applied to ASP server controls, they get rendered to HTML elements by the time they reach the browser. Are you familiar with your browser's developer tools? Try inspecting the form element and see if anything is being applied.

Comment: Take a look at the HTML that the browser sees. That is where your CSS is applied, so that's where you need to look when trying to debug it. The ASP code isn't really relevant. Having said that, your form element ought to be rendered unchanged in the HTML, and ought to be getting styled correctly. I'm not sure why it isn't. Try adding `display:block` to your styles; maybe that'll help.

Comment: *sigh* - so many .NET questions follow the same pattern. It's as if .NET was never for making web apps in the first place.